# The reference of the first figure in the appendix leads to the first figure in the main

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, appendix

I want the number of the figures in the appendix to be preceded by the letter `A`. 
Of course, I want their enumeration to start from `0`, and not from whatever was the number of the last figure in the main.

I try to do it in the following way:

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\appendix

\renewcommand\thefigure{A\arabic{figure}}
```

Then, I label any figure in a similar way as I do for the main, for example

```
\caption{\label{fig:appendix_bird}}
```

When I make the reference

```
Fig. \ref{fig:appendix_bird}
```

in the text it properly prints `Fig. A1`, as it should, but when I click on the number, it sends me to the first figure of the main instead.

If I remove `\setcounter{figure}{0}`, by clicking I am indeed sent in the appendix figure, but the numbering of the figures is just a continuation of the numbering of the main text.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) uses `\theH<cntr>` as a hyper reference hook for every hyperlink to a counter `<cntr>`. So, for `figure`, `\thefigure` prints the actual figure counter while `\theHfigure` manages the hyperlink. If the latter is not unique, you'll receive the following type of warning in your `.log` file:

> [1{c:/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}pdfTeX warning
>    (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.1}) has been already
>    used, duplicate ignored

So, ensure that if you're re-using document elements (in this case, `figure`s), you also update the `\theH<cntr>` representation so that it would distinguish between the original and re-used portions. For you, this is achieved by using

```
\appendix
\setcounter{figure}{0} % Restart figure numbering
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}% Figure counter representation
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{A\arabic{figure}}% Hyperref figure hyperlink hook
```